# jQuery autocomplete multiple fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the below AJAX response which is an object containing a food item and price.

```
{
   "pizza": "100.00", 
   "Burger": "45.00", 
   "Ice Cream": "25.00", 
   "Chips": "20.00", 
   "Peanut Butter": "50.00"
}
```

I'm trying to build a form wherein the user enters an item and the 'price' input field gets automatically filled. I went through the jQuery documentation and I'm confused as to how I can get the Item inputbox to only look for the 'food' items (or keys) in the array.

I'm getting a `this.source is not a function` in my console. I'm aware of the reason where I'm going wrong (I believe its due to the fact that they keys are different food items as opposed to 'label').

Here is my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var myItems = getData();

    $('#Item').autocomplete({
        source: myItems,
        focus: function(event,ui){
          $('#Item').val(ui.item.Item);
          return false;
        },
        select : function(event,ui){

          $('#Rate').val(ui.item.Price);
        }
    });
});

function getData(){
    var myItems = {};
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        async: false,
        url : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
        data : {},
        contentType: "application/json",
        crossDomain:true,
        success : function(json){
          for(i = 0; i <json.length; i++){
            myItems[json[i].Item] = json[i].Price;    
            //below doesn't work in loop
            // myItems['Item'] = json[i].Item;
            // myItems['Price'] = json[i].Price;
          }
        },
        error : function(response){
          console.log('error')
        }
    });
    // console.log('Is this working '+ myItems);
    console.log(myItems);
    return myItems;
};
```

Please let me know how I can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The [`source`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) option when you create the autocomplete needs to be either an Array of strings with the values, a String for a url with a JSON response that holds the values or a function callback which takes a pair of request and response parameters.

The way you have assigned `var myItems = getData();` means the `myItems` is not one of these types. It will currently be an empty object because it is assigned before your Ajax call will complete.

Assuming you only need to load the data once, create the autocomplete in the success callback for your Ajax request;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    getData();

    function getData(){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            async: false,
            url : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
            data : {},
            contentType: "application/json",
            crossDomain:true,
            success : function(json){
                var myItems = {};
                for(i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
                    myItems[json[i].Item] = json[i].Price;    
                }
                $('#Item').autocomplete({
                    source: myItems,
                    focus: function(event,ui){
                        $('#Item').val(ui.item.Item);
                        return false;
                    },
                    select : function(event,ui){
                        $('#Rate').val(ui.item.Price);
                    }
                });
            },
            error : function(response){
                console.log('error')
            }
        });
    };

});
```

Comment: Yea .. that makes sense. changed it .. any idea how i can get only the object keys for the autocomplete?

Comment: @Kunkka Sorry, just edited. I've just checked the API and I'm not sure you should use the function version for the source. All depends how often your data will change. When the source is a function it gets called every keystroke so making the Ajax request each time will perform really badly. The idea with the function version is to provide your own filtering.

Comment: I'm still getting a this.source is not a function. My doubt here is that the line **$('#Item').val(ui.item.Item);** , ui.item.Item does not refer to anything does it ? since its all seperate food names?

Comment: @Kunkka what is giving you that error? you can use `typeof myItems` to check it's a Function or not. You seem to have made it work by ensuring the source is an Array though.

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried going about this another way. i managed to pull all keys into a single array and use that as the source. the second box gets filled based on the value of the first box on the select event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var myItems = getData();

  var keys = [];
  for(var k in myItems){
    keys.push(k);
  }

  $('#Item').autocomplete({
    source: keys,
    select : function(e,ui){
      var value =  myItems[ui.item.value];
      $('#Rate').val(value);
    }
  });
});

function getData(){
  var myItems = {};
  $.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    async: false,
    url : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    data : {},
    contentType: "application/json",
    crossDomain:true,
    success : function(json){
      for(i = 0; i <json.length; i++){
        myItems[json[i].Item] = json[i].Price;
      }
    },
    error : function(response){
      console.log('error')
    }
  });
  // console.log(myItems);
  return myItems;
};
```